# TaskLauncher cloudfoundry Problems with Tasklaunching

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I try to use the task-launcher-cloudfoundry-sink-rabbit-1.2.0.RELEASE but when the Task is creating and is in Staging Mode the Task crashed. Any Ideas? the Tasklauncher log :

`2017-06-28T13:34:58.95+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2017-06-28 11:34:58.954  INFO 14 --- [yexp5qFW6l-Pw-1] o.s.c.task.launcher.TaskLauncherSink     : Launching Task for the following resource TaskLaunchRequest{uri='http://artifactor
2017-06-28T13:34:58.95+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2017-06-28 11:34:58.955  INFO 14 --- [yexp5qFW6l-Pw-1] o.s.c.d.r.s.DelegatingResourceLoader     : Reusing cached file /home/vcap/tmp/deployer-resource-cache5895756579145891352/http
2017-06-28T13:34:59.14+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2017-06-28 11:34:59.149 ERROR 14 --- [ry-client-nio-1] s.c.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher : Task Maus launch failed
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.ErrorPayloadMapper.lambda$null$10(ErrorPayloadMapper.java:107) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.0.RELEASE]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT org.cloudfoundry.client.v3.ClientV3Exception: CF-UnprocessableEntity(10008): The request is semantically invalid: Task must have a droplet. Specify droplet or assign current drople
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.ErrorPayloadMapper.lambda$null$3(ErrorPayloadMapper.java:65) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.0.RELEASE]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:412) ~[reactor-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoThenMap$MonoThenApplyMain.onNext(MonoThenMap.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114) ~[reactor-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:119) ~[reactor-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsing$UsingFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxUsing.java:320) ~[reactor-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:928) ~[reactor-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onHandlerTerminate(ChannelOperations.java:499) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:469) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoReduceSeed$ReduceSeedSubscriber.onComplete(MonoReduceSeed.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:315) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:427) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1228) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1039) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:642) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:565) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:479) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:441) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeek] :
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.core.publisher.Mono.checkpoint(Mono.java:1286)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        org.cloudfoundry.reactor.client.v3.tasks.ReactorTasks.create(ReactorTasks.java:58)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.requestCreateTask(CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.java:197)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.launchTask(CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.java:169)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.lambda$launch$0(CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.java:96)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.core.publisher.MonoThenMap$MonoThenApplyMain.onNext(MonoThenMap.java:100)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:928)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.core.publisher.MonoThenMap$MonoThenApplyMain$SecondSubscriber.onNext(MonoThenMap.java:202)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:165)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:78)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlattenSubscriber$InnerSubscriber.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:199)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:119)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsing$UsingFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxUsing.java:320)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:108)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:412)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:928)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.core.publisher.MonoReduceSeed$ReduceSeedSubscriber.onComplete(MonoReduceSeed.java:142)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:315)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:427)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onHandlerTerminate(ChannelOperations.java:499)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:469)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:271)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1228)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1039)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:642)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:565)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:479)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:441)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT        io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
2017-06-28T13:34:59.15+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Error has been observed by the

Answer (score 0):

The most common observation in this case could be the Task-API timeout. By default, the sink *(that uses the [cf-deployer](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry))* is configured to be at 30s. It is probably taking >30s for the PCF lifecycle of the task container and then the Task application itself needs to bootstrap after the fact.

You can change the timeout via `spring.cloud.deployer.cloudfoundry.api-timeout` property supplied in the DSL. More details [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-cloudfoundry/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-task-launcher-cloudfoundry/README.adoc#remote-repositories).

Comment: Okay  I use Release 2.0 the default Timeout 360 s is it right?

Comment: We have never made a 2.0 release, but in 1.2.0 of cf-deployer release, the timeout is bumped to 360s. Unfortunately, the `tasklauncher-sink` is not updated to the latest version yet, so it is still on the 30s as default - we have an [open PR](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-cloudfoundry/pull/11) and we will merge it soon.

Comment: We do not know if this is the cause of your problem. Please try overriding it first. If the issue remains, it'd be great if you can post the entire stacktrace (with caused by) - preferably DEBUG mode turned on.

Answer (score 0):

We changed the timeout to 360 seconds and now we get a different error. The Task launcher itself starts with no problems using the java buildpack offline. But the task cannot be launched. This is the log output of the failing task:

```
   2017-07-03T13:08:22.03+0200 [STG/0] ERR Failed to clone git repository at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git
   2017-07-03T13:08:22.03+0200 [STG/0] OUT Exit status 1
   2017-07-03T13:08:22.05+0200 [STG/0] ERR Staging failed: Exited with status 1
   2017-07-03T13:08:22.05+0200 [STG/0] OUT Destroying container
   2017-07-03T13:08:22.35+0200 [STG/0] OUT Successfully destroyed container
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It could help you to read some guidelines. Your post is not an answer to the question. Please read **[How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. For good questions read: **[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: @fallout: It is still unclear how you're orchestrating the task and with what configurations. As next steps, open a new issue in the [spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-cloudfoundry](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-cloudfoundry/issues) repo with as many details as articulated in the [wiki](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/wiki/Reporting-Issues). Also, it'd help if you can share the `manifest.yml`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I accidentally swapped comment with answer. We solved the problem by defining the java buildpack within the manifest.yml