# Unable to deploy/run tasks on Pivotal CF from Spring Cloud Dataflow container error CF-UnprocessableEntity(10008)

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

Trying to deploy a Java Spring Boot App/Task using Spring Cloud Data Flow. But it fails with foloowing exception

CF-UnprocessableEntity(10008): The request is semantically invalid: Task must have a droplet. Specify droplet or assign current droplet to app.

Tried the solutions below by SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_API-TIMEOUT to 720 and SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_TASK_TASK_TIMEOUT to 360 did not work.

[TaskLauncher cloudfoundry Problems with Tasklaunching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852607/tasklauncher-cloudfoundry-problems-with-tasklaunching)

https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-cloudfoundry/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-task-launcher-cloudfoundry/README.adoc#remote-repositories

Find Logs here -

2017-07-13T14:19:42.326+05:30 [RTR/0] [OUT] data-flow-server.apps.titan.lab.emc.com - [2017-07-13T08:49:42.285+0000] "GET /tasks/definitions?page=0&size=10&sort=DEFINITION_NAME,DEFINITION,ASC HTTP/1.0" 200 0 682 "https://data-flow-server.apps.titan.lab.emc.com/dashboard/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36" "172.16.7.103:56765" "172.16.4.167:62438" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"2a2ef33e-7be7-4771-7e2b-7453b00e5418" response_time:0.040391738 app_id:"405aad06-0bda-4b73-b0c4-b8d03a131fa5" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"de768721526b035b" x_b3_spanid:"de768721526b035b" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2017-07-13 08:49:42.954 ERROR 14 --- [ry-client-nio-1] s.c.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher : Task sampleDataFlowTask launch failed
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.cloudfoundry.client.v3.ClientV3Exception: CF-UnprocessableEntity(10008): The request is semantically invalid: Task must have a droplet. Specify droplet or assign current droplet to app.
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.ErrorPayloadMapper.lambda$null$3(ErrorPayloadMapper.java:65) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-2.14.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.14.0.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.ErrorPayloadMapper.lambda$null$10(ErrorPayloadMapper.java:108) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-2.14.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.14.0.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoThenMap$ThenMapMain.onNext(MonoThenMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:115) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsing$UsingFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxUsing.java:351) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:428) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:962) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoReduceSeed$ReduceSeedSubscriber.onComplete(MonoReduceSeed.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:130) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:375) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:198) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:338) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:343) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onHandlerTerminate(ChannelOperations.java:419) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:566) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:125) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1240) ~[netty-handler-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1041) ~[netty-handler-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:624) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:559) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:476) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[netty-common-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.956+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeek] :
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.Mono.checkpoint(Mono.java:1400)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.cloudfoundry.reactor.client.v3.tasks.ReactorTasks.create(ReactorTasks.java:58)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.requestCreateTask(CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.java:170)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.launchTask(CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.java:144)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.lambda$launch$0(CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.java:91)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.MonoThenMap$ThenMapMain.onNext(MonoThenMap.java:120)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:962)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.MonoThenMap$ThenMapMain$ThenMapInner.onNext(MonoThenMap.java:237)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:173)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:108)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:235)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:207)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:322)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:316)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:581)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:125)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.http.HttpOperations.lambda$static$3(HttpOperations.java:261)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.ReactorNetty$ExtractorHandler.channelRead(ReactorNetty.java:328)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1240)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1041)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:624)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:559)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:476)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Error has been observed by the following operator(s):
2017-07-13T14:19:42.957+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] |_ Mono.checkpoint(ReactorTasks.java:58)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2017-07-13 08:49:42.969 ERROR 14 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.c.d.s.c.RestControllerAdvice : Caught exception while handling a request
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.cloudfoundry.client.v3.ClientV3Exception: CF-UnprocessableEntity(10008): The request is semantically invalid: Task must have a droplet. Specify droplet or assign current droplet to app.
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.ErrorPayloadMapper.lambda$null$3(ErrorPayloadMapper.java:65) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-2.14.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.14.0.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.ErrorPayloadMapper.lambda$null$10(ErrorPayloadMapper.java:108) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-2.14.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.14.0.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoThenMap$ThenMapMain.onNext(MonoThenMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:115) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsing$UsingFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxUsing.java:351) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:428) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:962) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoReduceSeed$ReduceSeedSubscriber.onComplete(MonoReduceSeed.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:130) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:375) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:198) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:338) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:343) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onHandlerTerminate(ChannelOperations.java:419) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:566) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:125) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1240) ~[netty-handler-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1041) ~[netty-handler-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:624) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:559) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:476) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[netty-common-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeek] :
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.Mono.checkpoint(Mono.java:1400)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.cloudfoundry.reactor.client.v3.tasks.ReactorTasks.create(ReactorTasks.java:58)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.971+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.requestCreateTask(CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.java:170)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.launchTask(CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.java:144)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.lambda$launch$0(CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.java:91)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.MonoThenMap$ThenMapMain.onNext(MonoThenMap.java:120)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:962)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.MonoThenMap$ThenMapMain$ThenMapInner.onNext(MonoThenMap.java:237)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:173)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:108)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:235)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:207)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:322)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:316)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:581)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:125)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.http.HttpOperations.lambda$static$3(HttpOperations.java:261)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.ReactorNetty$ExtractorHandler.channelRead(ReactorNetty.java:328)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1240)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1041)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
2017-07-13T14:19:42.972+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)

Comment: As discussed on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44949029/spring-cloud-data-flow-on-cloudfoundry#comment77091289_45013459), were you able to resolve the feature invalid error? Please consider closing the old thread - it could get confusing for others looking for a solution. Also, it'd be great to gather as many details as possible when reporting a problem - here's a [handy list](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/wiki/Reporting-Issues) of what would be relevant to troubleshoot.

Comment: PFB version details.

Answer (score 0):

Data Flow Server Implementation

Name spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry Version 1.2.2.RELEASE Enabled Features

Analytics Y Streams Y Tasks Y

Security Information

Authentication Enabled X Authorization Enabled X Form Login X Authenticated X Username N/A Roles []

Version Information

Implementation 1.2.2.RELEASE (spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry) Core 1.2.2.RELEASE (Spring Cloud Data Flow Core) Dashboard 1.2.1.RELEASE (Spring Cloud Dataflow UI) Runtime Environment - App Deployer

Implementation Version 1.2.1.RELEASE Name CloudFoundryAppDeployer Spi Version 1.2.1.RELEASE Java Version 1.8.0_131 Platform Api Version 2.65.0 Platform Client Version 2.14.0.RELEASE Platform Host Version unknown Platform Type Cloud Foundry Spring Boot Version 1.5.4.RELEASE Spring Version 4.3.9.RELEASE Platform-specific Information of the App Deployer

API Endpoint https://api.system.titan.lab.emc.com Runtime Environment - Task Launcher

ImplementationVersion 1.2.1.RELEASE Name CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher Spi Version 1.2.1.RELEASE Java Version 1.8.0_131 Platform Api Version 2.65.0 Platform Client Version 2.14.0.RELEASE Platform Host Version unknown Platform Type Cloud Foundry Spring Boot Version 1.5.4.RELEASE Spring Version 4.3.9.RELEASE Platform-specific Information of the Task Launcher

API Endpoint https://api.system.titan.lab.emc.com

PCF version 1.11

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided details (`Platform Api Version 2.65.0`), it seems like you're running it approximately on [CF 248](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/248/#) / [PCF 1.9 release](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-9/pcf-release-notes/runtime-rn.html#1.9.30).

In other words, this is not on the latest PCF 1.11 release.

Tasks in PCF was GA'd since the 1.9 release. To troubleshoot this further, please [turn on](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_deployment_logs) the DEBUG logs for `cf-java-client`, repeat this exercise, and share the logs. Feel free to share them directly in a new [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/issues). It'd be great to also review the stream definitions in the report.